# FSL installation in Ubuntu 20.04 gives : [FAILED] Unknown shell type fish

Tags: 20.04, bash, software-installation, fish

I am trying to install FSL in Ubuntu 20.04 for the past 2 days, it is showing '[FAILED] Unknown shell type fish'. I got to learn the hard way that FSL doesn't support fish, so I switched the shell to bash and tried to do it again , shows the same error. I am following steps from [here](https://fsl.fmrib.ox.ac.uk/fsl/fslwiki/FslInstallation/Linux) and even tried the shell setup from https://fsl.fmrib.ox.ac.uk/fsl/fslwiki/FslInstallation/ShellSetup.

I tried reinstalling using the same script: `xyz@xyz:~/Downloads$ python2 fslinstaller.py`

Log from the terminal after installation:

```
Checking FSL package            
[OK] File downloaded  
Installing FSL software version 6.0.5...  
FSL exists in the current location, would you like to keep a backup of the old version (N.B. You will not be able to use the old version)? [no]:   
We require your password to continue...  
password:   
[OK] FSL software installed.  
Performing post install tasks  
Stage 1  
By installing this python distribution you agree to the license terms in
/usr/local/fsl/fslpython/LICENSE.txt  
100%
Stage 2  
100%
/tmp/fslpythonDeLN/fslpython_miniconda_installer.log  
Post install setup complete  
[OK] Post installation setup complete  
[FAILED] Unknown shell type fish  
Aborted
```

The fsl folder is installed at `/usr/local/fsl` but
I checked `echo $FSLDIR` and `which imcp` both of which are returning empty strings. Clearly installation has failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You "switched the shell to bash", but you don't say how.  Did you just run `bash` as a subshell, or did you *really* change your shell using `chsh`?  It sounds like the former, given the fact that it is still complaining that your shell is `fish`.

Try `chsh -s /usr/bin/bash`, then log out completely and log back in before trying the script again.  If that works, then hopefully you can set your shell back to `fish` after that, and either:

- Just drop to a `bash` subshell to run the FSL tools
- Examine the changes that the FSL installer makes to the `bash` startup scripts such as (but not limited to) `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile`.  Then replicate these in your `~/.config/fish/config.fish` (or a `~/.config/fish/conf.d/fsl.fish`)

If that doesn't work, then I'll be honest, it's going to be difficult for most any of us to help you further since FSL seems to be be very niche software with a non-free-as-in-speech license that requires you to sign up for marketing spam to even view the installation script.  That's just not something most of us here on Ask Ubuntu are going to be willing to do.  If I could do a quick look at the installation script, I might have more options for you to try if this one doesn't work.

If this doesn't work, I would recommend that you ask on the FSL mailing list that they link to on their front page.  It appears to be fairly active, and I don't see that you've asked this question there at this point.